# For with i0 variables

Tags: java, loops, variables, for-loop, structure

What does it mean this structure-

```
for (int i0 = 0; i0 < size; i0++) {
```

I found this using `SoapObject`.

I don't understand the difference between this and a normal for cycle.

Comment: `i0` is a variable name. There is no difference between `int i=0` and `int i0=0`. There are probably nested loops with variable names like `i1` , `i2` etc

Comment: `for(int _ = 0; _ < size; _++)` is a valid `for`-loop , too ;)

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman it won't be in Java 9 http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-August/010673.html

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple variable name. In java any variable name can contains one or more number. But variable name can not contains number at first place.

See the java variable name [naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, valid variable names can start with a letter (uppercase or lowercase) or an underscore (but **not** a number), followed by a sequence of letters (uppercase or lowercase), numbers and/or underscore. The regular expression for the recongition of a variable would be:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

(Source: [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/512671-regular-expression-for-valid-variable-name/) - ignore the C# code apart from the regex)

Therefore, `i0` is a perfectly valid variable name (where `0i` is **not**).